# Simple jQuery and CSS Navigation Randomly Not Working Correctly on Refresh... all browsers

Tags: jquery, css, random, navigation, nav

Okay, this seems to be the case in all browsers and resolutions. I'm brand new to coding, so I'm fairly sure it's a simple error I'm missing. I've asked a group of friends, and it seems to be the same for everyone. The navigation hover only works some of the time on the main coded layout (not fully coded yet). I pulled the navigation out by itself and it seems to work correctly 100% of the time.

You can view how it should work here: http://dperolio.com/newnav/css/

Here is where the problem is: http://dperolio.com/tealtop2

It may work for you initially, or it may not. If you spam refresh (Ctrl+R) it will sometimes work. When it doesn't work, it seems it just sits in the hover state no matter what (bold white links).

I appreciate any insight you can offer; again I'm fairly sure I just made some stupid mistake and hopefully someone more experienced can spot it and point it out for me? Thanks!

Comment: It's not working for me at all (Chromium 12/Ubuntu 11.04)...

Comment: Even the http://dperolio.com/newnav/css/ ? http://dperolio.com/tealtop2 should work some of the time. Try hitting ctrl+r about 3 times in 1 second. It might take quite a few refreshes, but it should work eventually... It's quite odd.

Comment: Oh, sorry: the [dperolio.com/newnav/css](http://dperolio.com/newnav/css) link works perfectly; it's the other page, http://dperolio.com/tealtop2, that fails. I should've been more clear; sorry! =)

Comment: Are you attaching any other external CSS.

Comment: Nope, just attaching the single style sheet (css/style.css)... The problem has to originate in the CSS of the other elements I coded on the page though. It's probably very sloppy and I made some mistake that is interfering with the functionality of the nav. That's the only thing I can think of. I just can't figure out what's wrong with the CSS.

Comment: I knew it was something stupid... It was because I had the external CSS listed after calling the jQuery and script instead of before. :| It took me 3 hours to figure that out. :( Thanks for the replies though!

Comment: It's ok.Mark as answer if you agree with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I knew it was something stupid... It was because I had the external CSS listed after calling the jQuery instead of before it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick demo I made for you:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#topnav li").prepend("<span></span>"); //Throws an empty span tag right before the a tag

  $("#topnav li").each(function() { //For each list item...
    var linkText = $(this).find("a").html(); //Find the text inside of the a tag
    $(this).find("span").show().html(linkText); //Add the text in the span tag
  });

  $("#topnav li").hover(function() { //On hover...
    $(this).find("span").stop().animate({
      marginTop: "-40" //Find the span tag and move it up 40 pixels
    }, 250);
  }, function() { //On hover out...
    $(this).find("span").stop().animate({
      marginTop: "0" //Move the span back to its original state (0px)
    }, 250);
  });

});
```

```css
ul#topnav {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  font-size: 1.1em;
}

ul#topnav li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  /*--Important - Masking out the hover state by default--*/
  float: left;
  height: 40px;
}

ul#topnav a,
ul#topnav span {
  /*--The <a> and <span> share the same properties since the <span>  will be a duplicate of the <a> tag--*/
  padding: 10px 20px;
  float: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  background: url(a_bg.gif) repeat-x;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  /*--Vertical alignment of text--*/
}

ul#topnav a {
  /*--This is basically the hover state of navigation--*/
  color: #555;
  background-position: left bottom;
}

ul#topnav span {
  /*--Default state of navigation--*/
  background-position: left top;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <ul id="topnav" class="v2">
    <li><a href="http://www.sohtanaka.com/">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.sohtanaka.com/web-design/web-design-services.php">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.sohtanaka.com/web-design/designbombscom/">Portfolio</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.sohtanaka.com/web-design-blog/">Blog</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.sohtanaka.com/about/">About</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```